# add new editable field for tfs work item

Tags: templates, tfs, edit

I am editing an existing work item type which we have called "Requirement".  To this I wish to add an additional string field that we can edit the value, search and sort on.

Using the TFS Process Editor I am able to edit the Requirement work item type in a GUI environment.  With this open, I created a field modeled after an existing field.  I then open the Layout tab and add this new field to the layout.

When I open an existing Requirement work item, the label for the new field is there, but no control appears to edit the value.

I can't figure out what I am missing.  Can someone direct me what the missing step is please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Fields tab, have you set the Type of the new field to String?
On the Layout tab, have you set the Type property of the control to FieldControl?